# Subscript outside of limit

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, plsql

I tried several times in my cmd running this code but every time it says subscript out of limit at line 1 at the Declare but I haven't found any problem
**what should I do?**

[image: This is my cmd and the code is under the image]

```
declare
    type namesarray is varray(5) of varchar2(10);
    type grades is varray(5) of integer;
    names namesarray;
    marks grades;
    total integer;
begin
    names := namesarray('Pronab','Kavita','Pritam','Ayan','Bpl');
    marks := grades(96,96,97,93,92,90);
    total := names.count;

    dbms_output.put_line('Total ' || total || 'Students' );

    for i in 1..total loop
        dbms_output.put_line('Student: ' || names(i) || 'Marks' || marks(i));
    end loop;
end;
/
```

ERROR:

> ORA-06532: Subscript outside of limit
>
> ORA-06512: at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this line is the issue:-

```
marks := grades(96,96,97,93,92,90);
```

The array grades is defined as being of length 5, but you are attempting to insert 6 elements

Comment: Thanks a lot i fix the problem now and i exactly get my expected result that was the line